# selector gadget is not highlighting or showing me the path

Tags: web-scraping, selector

I'm new to using selector gadget, I was trying to web scrap IMDB but when I select the title it takes me to the movie page instead of highlighting it. When I try to highlight something else to see if I can get it to work it only selects that and nothing else.

I tried loading it on another browser but still had the same issue. I tried right clicking so I wouldn't be loaded into another page.